# Change content based on radio button selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here are my radio buttons:

```
<div style="float: left; margin-top: 35px; margin-left: 38px;">
    <input type="radio" name="cat" class="styled" value="jersey" />
</div>
<div style="float: left; margin-left: 58px; margin-top: 35px;">
    <input type="radio" name="cat" class="styled" value="shorts" />
</div>
<div style="float: left; margin-left: 58px; margin-top: 35px;">
    <input type="radio" name="cat" class="styled" value="shirts" />
</div>
<div style="float: left; margin-left: 58px; margin-top: 35px;">
    <input type="radio" name="cat" class="styled" value="reversible" />
</div>
<div style="float: left; margin-left: 88px; margin-top: 35px;">
    <input type="radio" name="cat" class="styled" value="outerwear" />
</div>
<div style="float: left; margin-left: 88px; margin-top: 35px;">
    <input type="radio" name="cat" class="styled" value="helmets" />
</div>
<div style="float: left; margin-left: 68px; margin-top: 35px;">
    <input type="radio" name="cat" class="styled" value="other" />
</div>
```

I've tried multiple jquery solutions where if a certain radio button is selected, it will display unique content for that radio button. However, all of my attempts have failed and I am really not sure why (I do have other jquery scripts running, maybe conflicts?)

**So, for example...**

If radio button `"cat"` has a value of `"helmets"` selected, I'd like to display the content for `helmets`. If the value is changed to `"other"`, let's do away with `helmets` and display the content for `"other"`.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can we see what you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

### [**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/wkx49/1/)

**JS**

```
$('input[type=radio]').click(function(){
    $('.area').hide();
    $('#' + $(this).val()).show(); 
});
```

**CSS**

```
.area{
    display:none;
    background-color:yellow; 
    clear:both; 
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div style="float: left; margin-top: 35px; margin-left: 38px;"><input type="radio" name="cat" class="styled" value="jersey" /></div>
    <div style="float: left; margin-left: 58px; margin-top: 35px;"><input type="radio" name="cat" class="styled" value="shorts" /></div>
    <div style="float: left; margin-left: 58px; margin-top: 35px;"><input type="radio" name="cat" class="styled" value="shirts" /></div>
    <div style="float: left; margin-left: 58px; margin-top: 35px;"><input type="radio" name="cat" class="styled" value="reversible" /></div>
    <div style="float: left; margin-left: 88px; margin-top: 35px;"><input type="radio" name="cat" class="styled" value="outerwear" /></div>
    <div style="float: left; margin-left: 88px; margin-top: 35px;"><input type="radio" name="cat" class="styled" value="helmets" /></div>
    <div style="float: left; margin-left: 68px; margin-top: 35px;"><input type="radio" name="cat" class="styled" value="other" /></div>

<div class='area' id="jersey">jersey</div>
<div class='area' id="shorts">shorts</div>
<div class='area' id="shirts">shirts</div>
<div class='area' id="reversible">reversible</div>
<div class='area' id="outerwear">outerwear</div>
<div class='area' id="helmets">helmets</div>
<div class='area' id="other">other</div>
```

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking for, but it still doesn't work on my end. This definitely confirms my suspicions, Probably some sort of conflict with another script that I'll have to look into! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$('input[name=cat]').change(function() {
   alert($(this).val()); 
});
```

If your code alert the right value, you can use a switch to add the content you want where you want. If the result is not as expected, you'll need to provide us more details to find out what is going on.